# sql difference of time between two status

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two status of a package i.e. Dropped and Intransit, and both status are captured in different rows in database, so for Ex.

```
City1 Pkg1    Status    Change_Date
ABC   1234    Dropped   07-DEC-16 02.52.28.000000 PM
ABC   1234   Intransit  07-DEC-16 05.52.28.000000 PM
```

So, I need at City level what is the average of intransit minus Dropped timing for all package. In this example for Pkg 1 the difference is 3 hours, similarly want to get at a city level that 1000 packages have a difference of average 2.8 hours.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: What column type is `Change_Date` ?

Comment: I am using Oracle DB

Comment: Change_Date is in Date format

Answer (score 2):

What you should actually do is first Try to create the View which will make this single Table Entity to list the Package in single row.

Considering table structure be something like this

```
CREATE TABLE `packageList` (
  `cityId` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `packageId` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `changedate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

so your view shoult be created based on following Query

```
    CREATE VIEW packageStatus AS 
    SELECT 
    pl1.cityId as cityId ,
    pl1.packageId as packageId ,
    pl1.changeDate as DropTIme,
    pl2.changeDate as Picktime 
    FROM 
    `packageList` pl1 , `packageList` pl2 
    WHERE 
    pl1.status = "Droped" AND pl2.status = "Picked" 
    and pl1.packageId = pl2.packageId
```

Afterwards it is going to be the simple query of Group by on that view only some thing like below query

```
SELECT 
   tt.cityid,avg(DATEDIFF(tt.DropTIme,tt.Picktime))  
FROM 
   (SELECT 
    pl1.cityId as cityId ,
    pl1.packageId as packageId ,
    pl1.changeDate as DropTIme,
    pl2.changeDate as Picktime 
    FROM 
    `packageList` pl1 , `packageList` pl2 
    WHERE 
    pl1.status = "Droped" AND pl2.status = "Picked" 
    and pl1.packageId = pl2.packageId) as tmpTable tt Group BY cityId
```

Answer Using only Query with out creating view will be soome thing like as follows

`SELECT 
   cityid,avg(DATEDIFF(DropTIme,Picktime))

FROM 
   (SELECT 
    pl1.cityId as cityId ,
    pl1.packageId as packageId ,
    pl1.changeDate as DropTIme,
    pl2.changeDate as Picktime 
    FROM 
    packageList pl1 , packageList pl2 
    WHERE 
    pl1.status = "Droped" AND pl2.status = "Picked" 
    and pl1.packageId = pl2.packageId) as tmpTable 
    Group BY cityId`

Comment: the view is definitely the most elegant and performant way here, nice one

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but we are not allowed to create table, so is there a way to get the required output in the format of table mentioned earlier

Comment: you can use the temprarory table in that case this can be little slow but work for sure

Comment: String constants need to be put between single quotes in SQL. Double quotes are for identifiers. `"Dropped"` refers to a column named dropped. `'Dropped'` is a character value

Answer (score 0):

Just subtract the change_date from the previous change_date:

```
select city, Pkg, status, Change_Date, 
       change_date - 
           lag(change_date, 1, change_date) over (partition by pkg order by case status when 'Dropped' then 1 else 2 end ) as diff
where status in ('Dropped', 'Intransit')
from the_table;
```

The result of subtracting one `date` from another is a number representing the (fractional) days between those two values. So 8 hours would result in `0.33`

The `order by case status when 'Dropped' then 1 else 2 end` sorts the rows with status `Dropped` before those with a different status (assuming there are only two values)

You can wrap the above into a derived table to get the average duration from that:

```
select avg(diff)
from (
  select city, Pkg, status, Change_Date, 
         change_date - 
             lag(change_date, 1, change_date) over (partition by pkg order by case status when 'Dropped' then 1 else 2 end ) as diff
  where status in ('Dropped', 'Intransit')
  from the_table;
) t;
```

Comment: i actually have query related to the keywords `over` and `partition by` being supported by mysql ??

Comment: @Anandthakkar: No, MySQL still doesn't support [modern SQL](http://modern-sql.com/) (but the question was never tagged with `mysql`)

Comment: Correct actually the question seems to be related to oracle only but i was curious about in which db it seems to be supported as it seems a little new syntax for mysql devs so thought to ask you

Comment: @Anandthakkar: essentially all modern DBMS except MySQL support window functions.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to nest requests and you will have poor performance on large amount of packages I think. It would have been easier to have all this info in one row like that:

CityID    PkgID    Status   Intransit    Dropped

With your data model I think one correct SQL syntax would be something like (not tested):

```
Select avg(time), city
From (
    Select (b.dropped - c.transit) as time, a.city as city, a.packageId 
    From myTable a, 
         (Select d.Change_Date as dropped
        From myTable d
        where a.packageId = d.packageId and d.Status = 'Dropped') b,
         (Select e.Change_Date as transit
        From myTable e
        where a.packageId = e.packageId and d.Status = 'Intransit') c
)
Group By city
```

Comment: i believe we can't do "b.dropped - b.transit" as they are not date and just fixed status

Comment: Maybe you should test it before post as answer.  Correct me if I misunderstand, the `a`, `b` and `c` are cross join...

Comment: Maybe you can try to help instead of discouraging other to... I don't have oracle installed, I'm pretty sure my last version is close enough to something actually working.

Comment: In fact, your sql have multiple error, i.e. `a.package = d.packageId`? where is the package, and where is the packageId, as you stated the field is `PkgID`...

Comment: @Alex thanks corrected, it's just an example to indicate the way to follow, we don't even have the name of the table so...!

Comment: String constants need to be put between single quotes in SQL. Double quotes are for identifiers. `"Dropped"` refers to a column named dropped. `'Dropped'` is a character value